# Hyperlink column not working in SelectProperties of SP.Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink

SP.Search funciton to get the data and it's working fine without hyperlink. Here I have used testUrl column which is the hyperlink type but not able to get the values in select properties.

Codes:

```
let query: SearchQuery = {
            Querytext: '',
            RowLimit: 1000,
            EnableInterleaving: true,
            SelectProperties: ['Id', 'Title', 'testUrlOWSURHL','testUrl'],
            Properties: [{
                Name: "EnableDynamicGroups",
                Value: {
                  BoolVal: true,
                  QueryPropertyValueTypeIndex: 3
                }
              }],
            TrimDuplicates: false
           // EnableFQL:true
        };


        sp.search(query).then((rec: SearchResults) => {           
            console.log(rec.PrimarySearchResults);
        });
``
```

Comment: I have found managed properties and tried using all of the ways for the hyperlink but not success yet. URL is given https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint